# Grouping lambda

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

if I have a structure like this:

```
Batch  Amount
76  495.4
76  975.75
76  25
76  442.46
77  1335.12
77  2272.37
77  34.5
77  496.99
77  360
77  13
77  594.6
```

And I want to get something like

```
Batch  Amount
76    1938.61
77    5106.58
```

How the expression should be?

I started with something like:

```
batches.GroupBy(x => new { Batch = x.Batch, Amount = x.Amount });
```

But it's not quite the thing that I'm looking for. Help me to get it right. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close.  Try this:

```
batches.GroupBy(x => x.Batch, x => x.Amount).Select(g => new {
    Batch = g.Key,
    Amount = g.Sum()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The query will be look like:

```
var bs = from s in batches
            group s by s.Batch into g
            select new { Batch = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(p => p.Amount) };
```

Although I don't know what's the lambda equivalent would be

upd:

Resharper helps a lot! :)

```
var batches = bs .GroupBy(s => s.Batch).Select(
                g => new {Batch = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(p => p.Amount)});
```